# Checking if a group of vectors contain any subsets of one another as fast as possible

Tags: r, vector, duplicates, subset

My code works, but I'm using a nested for loop which can't be the best way to do this. Is there a quicker way to check if a list of vectors contain any other vectors that are subsets of another? For example, I have a list of vectors called "a" with an arbitrary number of vectors:

```
a = list()
a[[1]] = c(1, 2)
a[[2]] = c(2, 3, 5)
a[[3]] = c(1, 2, 4, 6)
a[[4]] = c(9, 4)
```

I want to check if a[[n]] is a subset of any other vector in the list. So in my example only a[[1]] is a subset of a[[3]] Here's my code so far.

```
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
  for (j in 1:length(a)) {
    if(all(a[[i]] %in% a[[j]]) && i != j) {
        #do stuff...
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially it's asking if the list contains duplicate vectors. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is using double `sapply`. I am not sure how efficient this is since it is more or less double loop as well, it's just less code.

```
sapply(seq_along(a), function(x) any(sapply(a[-x], 
                                    function(y) all(a[[x]] %in% y))))

#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It follows the same logic as yours. Looping over each list element and searching if it is a subset of any other list element. It returns logical vector indicating whether it's a subset or not.